# Can I extract zip file in s3-amazon

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have used "aws-sdk" with nodejs and I'm asking if i can unzip/extract zip file after upload it to s3 ? or not ?

cause of I have faced a problem that i have folders these have folders multi level and I not want to do a lot of loop and upload file by file !

Comment: You can upload a whole tree to s3 using the command line tools. No need to zip first

Comment: how ? I can upload folder whatever what inside ? @MatBailie

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html (--recursive)